# trouble reading file into two objects repeatedly without an infinite loop

Tags: c++

c++ beginner and first time poster here.

I'm reading a file consisting of a series of large numbers separated by semicolons.

I am trying to create a loop where the file is read into two objects (first number up to semicolon in first object, second number into second object), then print the two objects containing each number. After printing the first two, it should repeat with the next two numbers until the end of the file is reached.

I have been playing around with it a lot and can't get it to work. Two problems keep occurring:

1. Infinite loop
2. failure to read the number into an object

I currently have the operator >> overloaded as follows:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& fin, big& obj){
    char temp[size];
    char stop = ';';
    fin.get(temp, size, stop);
    //constructor converts temp to big
    obj = big(temp);
    return in;
}
```

I have the file opening correctly, and when I just use it on one object( in>>big1) it works properly and reads the first number.

But if I try to read into two objects (in>>big1>>big2) then only the first gets a number and second gets nothing (big1==1234 big2==0).

If I try to do this in a loop which is the end goal, then I just get an infinite loop of zero. This is the basic code I have right now of what I'm trying to do:

```
//file opens correctly
big big1, big2;

while (!fin.eof()){

    //read two numbers from file seperated by semicolon
    fin >> big1 >> big2;
    std::cout << big1 << "\n";
    std::cout << big2 << "\n";

    //repeat until end of file reached
}
fin.close();
return 0;
```

How can I write this so it will work? I've been trying many ways of writing it and nothing works, but it has to be possible.

Please help me if you can!

also note I can't use predefined classes like std::vector or std::string

Comment: Have you read the documentation for std::istream::get?

Comment: try fin.getline(buf, 10, ';'); where buf  = char[10] and use atoi() to convert text to int

Comment: `char c; while(fin >> big1 >> c >> big2){...}`

Comment: If there are more than one number on the same line you have to write a function for parsing the string accordingly

Comment: use `std::getline()` to read a line, then `std::istringstream` to parse the numbers from it.